# Can AppDynamics (AppD) calculate the number of messages consumed and published by an application from a JMS queue and topic?

Tags: appdynamics

I have an application that is being monitored by AppDynamics.  The application consumes from a JMS queue and publishes messages to a JMS topic.

I would like to create a widget that displays the number of messages it is consuming from the queue and the number of messages it is publishing to the topic.

How do I identify the data source of the queue and topic then retrieve the number of messages that the application is consuming and then publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the consumption of messages, these can be instrumented as Business Transactions (see https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/configure-instrumentation/transaction-detection-rules/message-queue-entry-points) - then the BT count will be the number of messages consumed.

For the publishing to a topic, these will be represented as exit calls to a backend (assuming this is not instrumented) - then the backend (a.k.a Remote Service) call count will be the number of pushes to the topic.

For actually directly getting the number of messages on a queue, you may want to use a Machine Agent extension:

e.g.

- WebSphere MQ: https://developer.cisco.com/codeexchange/github/repo/Appdynamics/websphere-mq-monitoring-extension
- ActiveMQ: https://developer.cisco.com/codeexchange/github/repo/Appdynamics/activemq-monitoring-extension
- RabbitMQ: https://developer.cisco.com/codeexchange/github/repo/Appdynamics/rabbitmq-monitoring-extension

Docs on using extensions can be found here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/infrastructure-visibility/machine-agent/extensions-and-custom-metrics